# Update iPhone NOT to latest version

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 4s with an iOS 7.1. I wish to update my phone to iOS 8 or 8.1 because most apps only support 8 or higher. I do not however want to update to the latest version supported on the 4s (iOS 9.3.5). Is there a way I could update by phone to iOS 8 and not iOS 9?

Answer (score 0):

What does **Software Update** in Settings show you? If it is iOS 9 then I'm afraid you can *not* upgrade to 8 via this route.

You cannot download iOS 8 unless Apple decides to start signing it again.

Comment: why the downvote? its a good answer, kinda thought not being able to update to IOS 8 was an obvious one, guess not. I mean oP could have used google, would have saved us the bother.